# ML Kit FaceDetectionProcessor not detecting the ears landmarks

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

## Issues details

I tried the ML Kit Face detection sample app from [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) but was not able to receive landmark data for the ears while running the LiveDataPreviewActivity.

The call face.getLandmark always returns null for FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR and FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EAR. All other landmarks are highlighted and retrieved just fine.

(Tested on Google Pixel and Samsung S6)

Anyone else encountered this issue? Is there some additional setup needed for detecting the ears? ... I also added a github issue to the repo, but I think the stackoverflow community is more active.

### Relevant code

```
drawLandmarkPosition(canvas, face, FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR)
drawLandmarkPosition(canvas, face, FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EAR)
...
private fun drawLandmarkPosition(canvas: Canvas, face: FirebaseVisionFace, landmarkID: Int) {
        val landmark = face.getLandmark(landmarkID)
        landmark?.let {
            val point = landmark.position
            canvas.drawCircle(
                    translateX(point.x),
                    translateY(point.y),
                    10f, idPaint)
        }
    }
```

... the ***landmark*** value is always null.

Code from: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/kotlin/facedetection/FaceGraphic.kt#L115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from firebase tech support (thanks again) and the missing thing was this line in app/build.gradle:
***implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2'***

Already created a pull request on github and hopefully it will get accepted.
Cheers! ;)